# How to use entity framework transaction in raw query?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

I am using entity framework but doing my operations with raw queries. My operations are like following:

1. Check if recırd exist with integration_id
2. Delete record if exit
3. Insert new record

So I am using transaction

```
using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{ 
        var isExist = await IsExist(id);

        if (isExist)
        {
              var deleteQuery = "delete from ....";
              await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(deleteQuery);
        }

        var insertQuery = "insert into ...";
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(insertQuery);
}
```

if insert operation fails, does deleted record rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#controlling-transactions

> transaction will auto-rollback when disposed if either commands fails

So, my code below may be overkill on the catch side, but Commit is still essential :)

======================

I believe the correct way of using transaction would be following:

```
using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    try
    {
        var isExist = await IsExist(id);

        if (isExist)
        {
            var deleteQuery = "delete from ....";
            await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(deleteQuery);
        }

        var insertQuery = "insert into ...";
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(insertQuery);

        // there we tell DB to finish the transaction,
        // mark all changes as permanent and release all locks
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // there we tell DB to discard all changes
        // made by this transaction that may be discarded
        transaction.Rollback();
        // log error
    }
}
```

But I never used `BeginTransaction*Async*` personally before.

Answer (score -1):

This method doesn't start transaction on it's own. If you need to execute queries in transaction you need to first call

```
BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade, IsolationLevel) or UseTransaction.
```

Reference
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-5.0)

So in your case it will execute queries in a transaction and roll back all the queries if any of the query failed

Comment: Can you give us an example?
I can't find anything about how to use your "BeginTransaction(...,...)".